# Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties when handling react children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component that provides its children to a child component. The children can either be a node or an array of nodes, and depending on if it is a node or an array of nodes the children in the ChildComponent are rendered differently. However, when I a render the ChildComponent in the ParentComponent, I get the following Typescript error:

> TS2786: 'ChildComponent' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type 'Element | Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.     Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

Please see the below for the code. How can I render the ChildComponent without any Typescript errors? Thanks!

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './component.scss';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactChildren;
}

const ChildComponent = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] => {
  if (React.Children.count(children)) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => (
      <div className={styles.childContainer}>{child}</div>
    ));
  }

  return <div className={styles.singleContainer}>{children}</div>;
};

const ParentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <ChildComponent>{children}</ChildComponent>
  </div>
);

export default ParentComponent;
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your current code, the return type is `JSX.Element[]` from `if` block (*incorrect*) but `JSX.Element` (*correct*) from `else` part. That's the reason of the error you are seeing.

To fix it, you need to return **single JSX expression** from `ChildComponent` as "JSX expressions must have one parent element".

You can use a parent element like `div`, `span` or simply use `React.Fragment` (shorthand `<></>`):

```
const ChildComponent = ({ children }: Props) => {
  if (React.Children.count(children)) {
    return (
      <>  // HERE
        {React.Children.map(children, (child) => (
          <div className={styles.childContainer}>{child}</div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
  return <div className={styles.singleContainer}>{children}</div>;
};
```

And `children` type should be `ReactNode` instead of `ReactChildren`:

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

As these are the definitions of both the typings:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;

interface ReactChildren {
  map<T, C>(children: C | C[], fn: (child: C, index: number) => T):
      C extends null | undefined ? C : Array<Exclude<T, boolean | null | undefined>>;
  forEach<C>(children: C | C[], fn: (child: C, index: number) => void): void;
  count(children: any): number;
  only<C>(children: C): C extends any[] ? never : C;
  toArray(children: ReactNode | ReactNode[]): Array<Exclude<ReactNode, boolean | null | undefined>>;
}
```

Also, I would suggest [not to use React.FC](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177).

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-fog-dc8v3?file=/src/App.tsx:103-431).

#### Edit:

**PS**: The else block `<div className={styles.singleContainer}>{children}</div>` and the `if` condition with `count` is not really required.